# Cannot install VisualSVN Server - error creating temporary file - Win 7

Tags: wmi, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. Every time I try to install the latest version of VisualSVN Server (3.3.1) I get an error saying it could not create any temporary files.

I really can't figure out what's causing this error. I am installing as an administrator.

[Here is a link to the installation logs](https://gist.github.com/Waveharp/63142c9cff96670e7822).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The only error message I see is "DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BottomLine on dialog FatalError extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 5 pixels".  There are [similar](https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/83460) reports online with this error in MSI logs where the issue was Windows Update.  I suspect it's a problem with Windows Installer.  There are [several](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6c6a8b45-d2a7-4fd9-940e-41dd9e77fb7e/windows-installer-corrupted) posts out there for how to fix Windows Installer when it's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error is:

> MSI (s) (F8!A8) [13:29:08:907]: Product: VisualSVN Server 3.3.1 -- Error 25000. Custom action InstallWMISchemaExecute failed: Error creating temporary file (0x8004402F)

The `0x8004402F` is Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) specific error code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559

So you have some issues with WMI on your computer. Suggested actions to troubleshoot this issue:

- run `sfc /scannow` command
- remove all files in `C:\Windows\Temp` directory
- remove all files in `%TEMP%` directory
- check that `LOCAL SYSTEM` account has full access to 'C:\Windows\Temp\ directory

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. 

I would have never suspected it was WMI, as other programs were installing fine.

I've got VisualSVN Server up and running just fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: It also makes sense to check the permissions to the user's %TEMP% directory. I.e., C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\. The error reproduces when I deny SYSTEM account access to this directory.